# Trouble with LAN (airline) refund - explanation of ticket fare policy codes

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, disputes

On my ticket for LAN I see:
NONEND-REF/CHG SEE PENALTY
which I believe does not mention to the ticket not being refundable. Also, in the receipt they sent me it states:

> **REFUNDS**
>   Please find the regulations regarding ticket refunds for each of your flights below. Remember that the most restrictive conditions of the fares that you bought will apply. In the event that you request a refund, we will deduct the highest penalty fee of the entire trip.
>
> - Although your trip may not allow a refund you are entitled to request the return of the boarding fees. Please remember that in some countries there is a service charge and that this amount is not refundable.
> - You can request ticket refunds in the Servicios de LAN.com section. For the fare: QLESPD6Y/DD20 of the family Base Refunds are permitted with a charge of US$200.00 . Refunds for tickets that have been partially used: It will be refunded with the difference between the value of the original ticket and the cost of the trip actually flown, minus the corresponding refund charge.

However when I called today to cancel the flight the LAN customer care insists that the fare is non-refundable...
Any advice?

@Trufa the part I quoted comes from the section "Refunds" in my ticket receipt. See below. I am not sure if it is consistent with what I see in the notes of the ticket, that is why I was asking for the meaning of the code: NONEND-REF/CHG SEE PENALTY (see also below)
The call center said something about that being the case if the ticket was originated in BR but since it originates in US it is non-refundable. I wonder what is the legal basis of this since everything from the web site where I bought the ticket to the receipt I got states the ticket is refundable with $200 fee.
Any advice is welcome.

[image: Receipt]

[image: Ticket details, pointing to the receipt above...]

Comment: Did you ask them what that note on your ticket meant ?

Comment: I have suggested a change to your question title. As it stands, "Trouble with LAN refund" made me expect an issue with getting the use of the hotel's local area network for internet access in the hotel room refunded.

Comment: @blackbird57 no, but I wanted to ask them only once I am informed.. they seemed adamant to convince me that their system says non-refundable so it is non-refundable...

Comment: Thanks @ZachLipton. Then I guess the open question is: why the ticket receipt expressely states the contrary "For the fare: QLESPD6Y/DD20 of the family Base Refunds are permitted with a charge of US$200.00" 
I foresee troubles in trying to get my refund :(

Comment: And is that the only fare on which you are ticketed? Your entire reservation may consist of one or more fares.

Comment: yes QLESPD6Y is the only fare for all the segments of the flight.

Comment: When did you purchase this fare? This exact fare is no longer available but I can look at the historic fare information if you like.

Comment: Just for completeness, can you confirm that you are trying to cancel the booking and get a refund for flights in the future?

Comment: @ZachLipton, wouldn't "not endorsable or refundable" be written as "NONEND/NONREF"?

Comment: @Calchas I purchased this fare on March 10th, it would be great if you can retrieve teh historic fare info.

Comment: @jcaron  I am trying to cancel the booking and get a refund on the credit card (minus the $200 fee) because changing would be a $150 fee anyway plus the fare difference so I prefer the money back at this point. I agree that in my understanding it should  be NONEND/NONREF if it was non refundable. See also Calchas comment below

Comment: An update: I called the call center and this time the rep said that what I see on my receipt is correct ($200 fee) and he went on cancelling the booking and entering a request for refund. However the confirmation email the system sent does not show the refund amount, nor he was able to tell me the amount that will be refunded once I asked him at the end of the call ... 
I hope I don't end up without flight and without refund at this point, but to me it looks clear what my rights are so I would send it to DOT and then to small claims court if necessary. Hopefully won't get to that though.

Answer (score 3):

**NONEND** - Is short for "non endorsable". It means the ticket cannot be used ("endorsed") for travel on a different airline to the one that is specified on the ticket. In this case, you must use it on LAN. [In the old days if you bought a fully flexible paper ticket, you could take it to any airline counter you wanted and that airline would accept it for carriage on the next available flight. To provision this sometimes the issuing airline had to "endorse" the change of airline by marking the ticket before the second airline could accept it.]

**REF/CHG SEE PENALTY** - Means if you want to make refunds or changes, you need to see the penalties category of the fare(s) used to construct this ticket. You cannot assume this is a fully flexible, fully refundable ticket. [In the old days, most plane tickets were fully flexible and fully refundable, so it was a special case that changes were not allowed.]

These are technical terms that are not intended for interpretation by the customer.

Comment: Thanks!
So it is consistent with what I see in the Receipt which says "For the fare: QLESPD6Y/DD20 of the family Base Refunds are permitted with a charge of US$200.00 "
I will try to explain this to LAN customer care. No success so far...

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer: I am subcontracted by LAN, this is just my personal attempt to help the OP and not an official answer.**

---

I think you cut the purchase receipt's quote too early.

[Here is an example purchase receipt.](http://www.lan.com/upload/pdf/CUV_comprobante_unico_de_venta.pdf) (Sorry, couldn't find one in english, you can find yours [here](http://www.lan.com/cgi-bin/encontrar_cuv/paso1.cgi) but I guess you already have it).

Under the section `Cambios y devoluciones` (change and refund):

[image]

It will say `Refund:`

If there there it says that it doesn't allow refunds, unfortunately there isn't much you can do as far as I'm aware.

You could always contact the call center and insist since they are the ones that know the nooks and crannies and might help you find an exception if there is one, but I doubt so, nothing lost for trying though.

Comment: the part I quoted comes from the section "Refunds" in my ticket receipt, and it is all it says. I edited teh question above adding the image.  I am not sure if it is consistent with what I see in the notes of the ticket, that is why I was asking for the meaning of teh code: NONEND-REF/CHG SEE PENALTY (see also in the question)

Comment: @StefanoMelucci I will take a look and come back to you.